# Laptop battery drains fully when left over night

Tags: laptop, battery

My brand spankin' new HP Envy laptop drains the whole battery when I let it sit overnight. I simply close the lid (and have it set to go into sleep mode when I do so). What can I do to put an end to that? Thanks for your help,

Dan

Comment: Sleeping is not working.  Update your Power Driver, restart, check your Sleep settings for certainty. With ordinary sleep, any new laptop will last for more than 24 hours.

Comment: Some app/service prevents laptop from sleep mode. You can investigate or try with "hibernate" instead of sleeping

Comment: "My brand spankin' new" means that you get support.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Change the setting of what should be done when closing the lid. Windows and Linux have options for that. Look for it.

Comment: Yeah so switching it to hibernate works. The battery had plenty of charge left this morning. Why is that? I don't understand the difference between sleep and hibernate. Especially since sleep mode, on my old computer of the exact same product line (HP Envy), did not drain the battery.